# paypal invalid transaction id

Tags: asp.net, paypal

I am implementing the Paypal Express Checkout functionality in asp.net project that requires authorization and then voiding or capturing the authorized amount. I'm using their API of version=104.0.

As far as I understand the whole process, I am doing everything correctly:

- I call SetExpressCheckout method with ActionType set to "Authorize" in Payment Details

  ```
  SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType reqDetails = new SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType();
  reqDetails.ReturnURL = "http://some.url";
  reqDetails.CancelURL = "http://some.url";
  reqDetails.NoShipping = "1";
  reqDetails.OrderDescription = "You're about to buy items for " + payment.Amount.ToString("F");
  reqDetails.cpplogoimage = "http://some.ulr/image.jpb";
  reqDetails.PaymentDetails = new PaymentDetailsType[1];
  reqDetails.PaymentDetails[0] = new PaymentDetailsType();
  reqDetails.PaymentDetails[0].PaymentDetailsItem = new PaymentDetailsItemType[cart.LineItems.Count];
  int i = 0;
  foreach (LineItemModel li in cart.LineItems)
  {
      PaymentDetailsItemType item = new PaymentDetailsItemType();
      item.Amount = new BasicAmountType();
      item.Amount.Value = li.TotalIncludingShipping.ToString("F");
      item.Amount.currencyID = CurrencyCodeType.AUD;
      item.Name = li.ProductItem.DisplayName;
      item.Number = li.ProductItem.SKU;
      item.Quantity = li.Quantity.ToString();
      item.Description = "";
      reqDetails.PaymentDetails[0].PaymentDetailsItem.SetValue(item, i);
      i++;
  }
  reqDetails.OrderTotal = new BasicAmountType()
  {
      currencyID = CurrencyCodeType.AUD,
      Value = payment.Amount.ToString("F")
  };
  reqDetails.PaymentDetails[0].PaymentAction = PaymentActionCodeType.Authorization;
  reqDetails.PaymentDetails[0].PaymentActionSpecified = true;
  SetExpressCheckoutReq req = new SetExpressCheckoutReq()
  {
      SetExpressCheckoutRequest = new SetExpressCheckoutRequestType()
      {
          Version = "104.0",
          SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails = reqDetails
      }
  };
  ```
- it goes fine and in the back-end of Paypal in the Notification for my test Personal account I can see the message that the amount of money was autorized
- Then I call DoExpressCheckout. Here is the code of request

  ```
  DoExpressCheckoutPaymentReq payReq = new DoExpressCheckoutPaymentReq()
  {
      DoExpressCheckoutPaymentRequest = new DoExpressCheckoutPaymentRequestType()
      {
          Version = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PaypalAPIVersion"],
          DoExpressCheckoutPaymentRequestDetails = new DoExpressCheckoutPaymentRequestDetailsType()
          {
               Token = token,
               PayerID = payerID,
               PaymentDetails = new PaymentDetailsType[1]
          }
      }
  };           
  payReq.DoExpressCheckoutPaymentRequest.DoExpressCheckoutPaymentRequestDetails.PaymentAction = PaymentActionCodeType.Authorization;
  payReq.DoExpressCheckoutPaymentRequest.DoExpressCheckoutPaymentRequestDetails.PaymentActionSpecified = true;
  payReq.DoExpressCheckoutPaymentRequest.DoExpressCheckoutPaymentRequestDetails.PaymentDetails[0] = new PaymentDetailsType();
  payReq.DoExpressCheckoutPaymentRequest.DoExpressCheckoutPaymentRequestDetails.PaymentDetails[0].PaymentAction = PaymentActionCodeType.Authorization;
  payReq.DoExpressCheckoutPaymentRequest.DoExpressCheckoutPaymentRequestDetails.PaymentDetails[0].PaymentActionSpecified = true;
  payReq.DoExpressCheckoutPaymentRequest.DoExpressCheckoutPaymentRequestDetails.PaymentDetails[0].OrderTotal = new BasicAmountType();
  payReq.DoExpressCheckoutPaymentRequest.DoExpressCheckoutPaymentRequestDetails.PaymentDetails[0].OrderTotal.currencyID = CurrencyCodeType.AUD;
  payReq.DoExpressCheckoutPaymentRequest.DoExpressCheckoutPaymentRequestDetails.PaymentDetails[0].OrderTotal.Value = total.ToString("F");
  ```
- This request returns "Success" too. I save response's DoExpressCheckoutPaymentResponseDetails.PaymentInfo[0].TransactionID for future use
- But when I run DoAuthorize with the transaction ID from the previous response, I get "Failure". Here is the request code:

  ```
  DoAuthorizationReq authReq = new DoAuthorizationReq()
  {
      DoAuthorizationRequest = new DoAuthorizationRequestType() 
      {
          Version = "104.0",
          TransactionID = doCheckoutTransactionId
      }
  };
  authReq.DoAuthorizationRequest.Amount = new BasicAmountType();
  authReq.DoAuthorizationRequest.Amount.currencyID = CurrencyCodeType.AUD;
  authReq.DoAuthorizationRequest.Amount.Value = total.ToString("F");
  ```

The response says "Failure" and Errors array contains 1 item with ErrorCode=10609 and Message "Invalid Transaction ID"

Do you have any thoughts why this is happening?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To capture the funds after authorization you need to run DoCapture, not DoAuthorization.

Comment: But to run DoCapture, I need Authorization Transaction ID that I can get only by running DoAuthorization that does not work for me.

Comment: DoAuthorization is just the direct way to do it, and in fact they don't recommend using it anymore.  Instead, you run Express Checkout or Payments Pro as an authorization and then follow that up with Docapture.  Glad you got it working.